# How to stick back Google Chrome window to its parent window?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

In Google Chrome browser, we can make a tab to open in a new window by dragging it and releasing. In reverse, is there any way to stick the opened windows back to its parent window as a tab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

drag the tab in the "child" window back to the tab bar of the "parent" chrome window.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice lake. Where is it?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: It's not a lake :-) it's Derwent Water, Cumbria, UK. Looking towards Catbells from the opposite shore.

Comment: Cool :) My background is Lake Buttermere http://www.stevecarter.com/a1280-2.jpg