# Why does a tab move from existing Chrome window to a new one?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

Sometimes when I click on a tab in Chrome the window opens, but in a new browser. This does not seem to be related to quick-clicking. How can I return the new window back to the group?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stick back Google Chrome window to its parent window?](http://superuser.com/questions/463855/how-to-stick-back-google-chrome-window-to-its-parent-window)

Comment: What do you mean by “clicking on a tab”? Do you mean an existing tab? Is it only when the browser window is maximized/non-maximized? Are you simply happening to be dragging the tab out of the window? Try adjusting your [drag-threshold](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/fixing-annoyances-stop-windows-from-copying-files-accidentally-when-ctrl-click-selecting/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you may have dragged the mouse down a millimeter when you clicked the tab, therefore dragging it off the tab bar and into its own separate windows, IE has the same function, just click the same spot and drag it back into the main window.

Comment: I understand why it happens. But, it does not drag back. the only way I have found is to launch a new tab and copy the url.

Comment: Do you have the main window up directly behind that one? If you do not, you be able to, simply click the tab on your taskbar for the main window, then the tab for the chrome tab you pulled into its own window, and then drag.